# RequireJS build error [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, gruntjs, bower

I'm trying to build my Grunt/RequireJS app with the requirejs:production task, and I'm getting the following output:

```
Running "requirejs:production" (requirejs) task
>> Tracing dependencies for: ../bower_components/almond/almond
>> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>> In module tree:
>>     main
>>       models/session
>>         views/root
>>           navigation
>>             permissions
>>               text
{ [Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
In module tree:
    main
      models/session
        views/root
          navigation
            permissions
              text
]
  originalError:
   { [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
     moduleTree:
      [ 'text',
        'permissions',
        'navigation',
        'views/root',
        'models/session',
        'main' ],
     fileName: '/Users/zensavona/softwaredev/projects/haze/t3-web/web-admin/src/main/bower_components/text/text.js' } }
```

I think the code it's talking about is:

```
define(["backbone", "models/permissions", "text!/ducks/api/Permissions/Current"],
  function(Backbone, Permissions, permissionJSON) {
    if (permissionJSON.indexOf("<center><h2>Login</h2></center>") > -1) {
      return new Permissions();
    } else {
      var data = JSON.parse(permissionJSON);
      return new Permissions(data);
  }
});
```

My first instinct was a circular dependency of some kind (?) but I can't see one. Is this to do with my code or the `text` module?

Comment: Did you try setting `inlineText:false` in your [r.js config](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/2.1.14/build/example.build.js#L237)? Your error looks consistent with trying to read run-time information at build-time. However, your problem and the solution/workaround indicates an architecture problem and mixing abstractions and concerns. This just begs for using JS promises and most likely changing your logic a bit.

Comment: @kryger I had the same problem and solved it with your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I could not solve this and fixed it by removing `text` all together. Luckily this was the only place I needed it, and I replaced it with an `async: false` jQuery call (see below).

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "models/permissions"],
  function($, Backbone, Permissions) {
    var permissionJSON = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/ducks/api/Permissions/Current',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
          permissionJSON = data;
        }
    });

    if (permissionJSON.indexOf("<center><h2>Login</h2></center>") > -1) {
      return new Permissions();
    } else {
      return new Permissions(permissionJSON);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with requireJS 2.1.15. The problem seemed to be that the `html` extension was not part of the of the path.

```
define([
    ...
    'text!templates/user/elements/profile.moderate.menu' //.html extension is missing
]...
```

Things started working once I added the extension

```
define([
    ...
    'text!templates/user/elements/profile.moderate.menu.html'
]...
```